Delete and update data at the same time in Laravel Ajax dynamic form
I have a form divided into two sections, a regular product form and a dynamic form for the product details below the regular one. I can successfully update or create new data. Now I tried using Ajax for the deletion process.
However, when I tried to delete a row in the dynamic form, the row had not been deleted. When I click submit to update all of the data in product form (the regular form and the dynamic one), it returns the success message for the deletion process. Still, the data has not been deleted from the database.
The controller works fine when I update old data, create new data without updating it, and create new data + update the old one. It's just not working when I try to do the delete process. What I want to achieve is to keep updating the existing data while deleting the removed data.
Dynamic Form Design
Please check the design here. I couldn't post it as image because it needs 10 reputations.
Dynamic form design
View Code
<form id="form1" class="ecommerce-form action-buttons-fixed" action="{{ route('products.update',$products->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   @method('PUT')

   <!--Regular form field here-->

   <!--Dynamic Form-->
   @foreach($specifications as $i => $spec)
       <input type="hidden" name="specifications[{{$i}}][id]" value="{{$spec->id}}">

       <div class="form-group row justify-content-center product-spec-row pb-3" id="index_{{ $spec->id }}">
          <div class="col-xl-6">
             <label class="control-label">Name</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-modern @error('spec_name') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Specification Name" name="specifications[{{$i}}][spec_name]" value="{{$spec->spec_name}}" />

           </div>
           <div class="col-xl-6">
               <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="product-spec-remove text-color-danger float-end">Remove</a>
               <label class="control-label">Value(s)</label>
               <textarea class="form-control form-control-modern @error('value') is-invalid @enderror" name="specifications[{{$i}}][value]" rows="4" placeholder="Enter some text">{{$spec->value}}</textarea>
           </div>
       </div>

      @endforeach

      </div>
      <div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
         <div class="col-xl-9 text-end">
            <a href="#" class="product-spec-add-new btn btn-primary btn-px-4 btn-py-2">+ Add New</a>
        </div>
      </div>
     <!--Dynamic Form End-->       

     </form>

Script
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.product-spec-remove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let spec_id = $(this).data('id');
    let token   = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");

    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Apakah Kamu Yakin?',
        text: "ingin menghapus data ini!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText: 'TIDAK',
        confirmButtonText: 'YA, HAPUS!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {

            console.log('test');

            //fetch to delete data
            $.ajax({

                url: `/specdelete/${spec_id}`,
                type: "DELETE",
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    "_token": token
                },
                success:function(response){

                    //show success message
                    Swal.fire({
                        type: 'success',
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: `${response.message}`,
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 3000
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    })

    $(`#index_${spec_id}`).remove();
   // $(this).closest('.product-spec-row').remove();
});

Controller
foreach ($request->specifications as $key => $specs) {

        // Update
        if (isset($specs['id']) && $specs['id']) {
            $data = ProductSpecification::where('id', $specs['id'])->first();
            $data->product_id = $products->id;
            $data->spec_name = $specs['spec_name'];
            $data->value = $specs['value'];
            $data->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
            // Create
        } else {
            $data = new ProductSpecification();
            $data->product_id = $products->id;
            $data->spec_name = $specs['spec_name'];
            $data->value = $specs['value'];
            $data->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
        }
            ProductSpecification::where('id', $id)->delete();

            //return response
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Detail Produk Berhasil Dihapus!.',
            ]);
        $data->save();
    }

Route
Route::post('/specdelete/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'deleteSpecification'])->name('deletespecification');
Route::resource('products', ProductsController::class);

Please help because I'm still a beginner at making dynamic forms like this. I appreciate your help.
